# How do I get the content excerpt of the recent post?

Tags: php, theme-development, recent-posts

Hi I am needing some help trying to add the recent post excerpt to the bottom left div of my webpage.

below is the piece of code that I'm having problems with in-between the p tags. I can display the post title and the ID, But cant get the recent post content or the recent post excerpt.

```
     <!-- //start -->
               <h2>Recent Post</h2>
            <div class="recent-post-holder">

           
             <div class="recent-image-holder"><img  class="recent-image" src="images/feeding.jpg" alt=""></div>

            
             <?php 
              $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
               $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                 
               foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {

                echo ' <div class="recent-text-holder"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . $recent["post_title"]. '</a>
                <p>' . get_the_excerpt(). '</p> </div> '; 

     } ?>
```

I just want to add the post content in-between the `<p>` tags not sure were I'm going wrong iv tried the following in-between the p tags:

```php
    $recent[post_excerpt]
    the_content()
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this I've looked through other similar post, But I cant get it to display the content. I was not sure if I need to create a while loop within the code to then return the post content, I'm not sure.

I am new to php and any help on this I would be grateful

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the ID, like you did for the link and title.

Try:

```
get_the_excerpt( $recent["ID"] )
```

Comment: That did work thanks alot, Funny I did try the_except($recent["ID]) before but now im reading the difference between the two and the_except($recent["ID]) does not take in a argument from what I read and the one you recommended get_the_excerpt( $recent["ID"] )  does. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please accept it by clicking on the green check mark next to the answer.